# PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, heroku-postgres

I have the following error when I try to run

```
git heroku push master
```

I don't how solve the problem. I am using rails 3.2.19

```
 fernando@fernando:~/ProyectoTicketMaster/Ticket_Master$ git push  heroku master 

Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
       rake aborted!
       PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_dd87fdc88ebb265d09b8212e3b0df10b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_dd87fdc88ebb265d09b8212e3b0df10b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `new'
       /tmp/build_dd87fdc88ebb265d09b8212e3b0df10b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `connect'
```

this is my GemFile. I'm using pg for production and sqlite for development. Here attached my GemFile and my databse.yml

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'

end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end


gem 'hirb'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'


development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding the following line in config/application.rb was the solution to my problem

```
 config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Comment: where is it? what is it? no explanation at all?

Comment: This should be added in `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 3):

Several things might cause this problem.

Do you have postgres running? Have you added it to your server?

Have you installed gem for pg?

Your setup should look like:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: user
  database: app-dev
```

You can take a look at this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-ruby, it will probably help :)

NOTE:: This should be comment but I don't have enough repoutation to comment.

Comment: I install gem 'pg', but I don't have installed postgres in my machine. How I install it? How I verify the version of postgres have installed in my ubuntu 12.04? Can be it the problem?

Comment: I think this link might help: http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/04/27/how-to-setup-postgresql-for-rails-and-heroku/ . Please upvote if you find something helpfull :)

Comment: Seems like you have defined adapters for sqlite3, if you are using postgres change that as well. I have sent you format for pg.

Comment: I'm using postgres in production for work with heroku  group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

Comment: I am talking about the end of your snippet. you have following: development: adapter:sqlite3, production: adapter:slqite3 etc.